# How to save json from server in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm creating an app which recognize the text from image. And I don't know how to save json result from server.

CameraScreen.js:

In CameraScreen user take picture, which contains a text and the picture send to the server. It return a json.

```
const postToServer = async (img) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('image', {
                uri: img.uri,
                type: 'image/jpeg', 
                name: 'test.jpg',
            })
    formData.append('title', 'title');
        
        let res = await fetch('http://192.168.0.149:8000/api/textocr/', { //http://192.168.0.149:8000/api/textocr/ HomeNetwork
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        });
        let json = await res.json();
        Alert.alert('Result', JSON.stringify(json));
  }
```

I want to each result will save and all results display on another screen.

HistoryScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { icons, theme } from '../../constrants';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

//Localization
i18n.defaultLocale = "ru";
i18n.translations = {
  en: { buttonHistoryBack: 'Go Back', titleHistory: 'History' },
  ru: { buttonHistoryBack: 'Вернуться', titleHistory: 'История' },
};
// Set the locale once at the beginning of your app.
i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
// When a value is missing from a language it'll fallback to another language with the key present.
i18n.fallbacks = true;

export default function HistoryScreen({ navigation }) {

const { COLORS, FONTS, SIZES } = theme;

const HistoryData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'OCR text anything...',
    datatime: '31.10.2021'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'OCR text anything...',
    datatime: '31.10.2021'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'OCR text anything...',
    datatime: '31.10.2021'
  },
];

const renderHistoryItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.HistoryItem, styles.shadowProp]}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("HistoryEditor")}>
        <View style={{width: 300, height: 84, borderRadius: 15, justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 15, paddingVertical: 10}}>
          <Text style={{...FONTS.name}}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={{...FONTS.name, color: '#9A9A9A'}}>{item.datatime}</Text>
        </View>
        <Image source={icons.next} resizeMode='contain' style={{ width: 20, height: 20, alignSelf: 'flex-end', paddingBottom: 84}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

  return (    
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="dark" />
      {/* Header */}
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.headerbutton}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} onPress={navigation.goBack}>
            <Image 
              source={icons.back}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
            />
            <Text style={{...FONTS.backbutton, color: COLORS.black, paddingTop: 2}}>{i18n.t('buttonHistoryBack')}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{...FONTS.title, paddingTop: 64}}>{i18n.t('titleHistory')}</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            borderBottomColor: 'black',
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            paddingTop: 4,
          }}
        />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.content}>
          <FlatList
            data={HistoryData}
            renderItem = {renderHistoryItem}
            keyExtractor = {(item) => item.id}
            />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F4F4F6',
  },
  header: {
    flex: 0.2,
  },
  headerbutton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 0.8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  shadowProp: {
    shadowColor: '#171717',
    shadowOffset: {width: -2, height: 4},
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 3,
  },
  HistoryItem: {
    backgroundColor: '#FBFBFB', 
    width: 350, 
    height: 84, 
    borderRadius: 15, 
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Where do you want to save the ?

Comment: What do you mean by "display on another screen"?

Comment: i mean i have history screen, where will flatlist with these results

Comment: Can you also post your code with `HistoryScreen` component and provide full code with your `CameraScreen`? If I understand this correctly, you want to store data fetched from server and display it in your `HistoryScreen` component?

Comment: Yes you're right) I post the code

Comment: you can pass json as prop to HistoryScreen when you navigate to HistoryScreen from your CameraScreen

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass JSON as props as so

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])

let json = await res.json();
setImages(json)
```

as props to your History screen
If rendering as a component like

```
 <HistoryScreen images={images}/>
```

If with navigation

```
navigation.navigate('HistoryScreen',{images})
```